# Method cascading possible when using Dart's async/await?

Tags: dart

I am hoping this is a simple question, but could not find the answer.  In synchronous Dart code, you can do method cascades like:

```
var obj1 = new SomeClass()
  ..method1()
  ..method2(param1, param2)
  ..method3();
```

Supposed that instead, those methods return Futures for asynchronous code.  So now it seems we have to do:

```
var obj1 = new SomeClass();

await obj1.method1();
await obj1.method2(param1, param2);
await obj1.method3();
```

Do method cascades work with the whole async/await constructs?  If so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like this is not (yet) supported.
There is an open issue https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23000

Comment: That proposal works for me.  Works better than what I was hoping would work, since appears to allow chaining a mix of synchronous/asynchronous code.  Looks like there's a while to wait for it, though....at any rate, thanks for the help and answer.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has a high priority.

Comment: Pretty sad that they closed the proposal. The only one that remains open is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25986, which does not look as nice as 23000.